Refresh screen of bottom navigation bar according to the clicked one in Flutter

i want to refresh the screen of bottom navigation bar according to the item which is clicked.
here is part of my tabscreen code.
    void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    if (index == _selectedIndex) {
      _navigatorKeys[index].currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
    }

    Widget _buildNavigator(GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey, Widget child) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => child);
      },
    );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: [
          _buildNavigator(
            _navigatorKeys[0],
            HomepageScreen(key: UniqueKey(), user: _user, cart: _cart),
          ),
          _buildNavigator(
            _navigatorKeys[1],
            OrderScreen(key: UniqueKey(), cart: _cart),
          ),
          _buildNavigator(
            _navigatorKeys[2],
            MenuScreen(key: UniqueKey(), user: _user, cart: _cart),
          ),
          _buildNavigator(
            _navigatorKeys[3],
            const RewardScreen(),
          ),
          _buildNavigator(
            _navigatorKeys[4],
            ProfileScreen(key: UniqueKey(), user: _user),`your text`
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MoltenBottomNavigationBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTabChange: _onTabTapped,
        tabs: [
          MoltenTab(icon: const Icon(Icons.home)),
          MoltenTab(icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined)),
          MoltenTab(icon: const Icon(Icons.restaurant)),
          MoltenTab(icon: const Icon(Icons.card_giftcard)),
          MoltenTab(icon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
        ],
      ),
      );
      }

refresh the screen according to the clicked one in bottom navigation bar.
now its not refreshiong the screen whenever i go to the clicked screen. Such as clicking orderscreen doesn't refreshes every time click. i want to refresh the screen when i click to the orderscreen button
